# Unexpected error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am getting the above error when I am trying to run this function on a text column in power query[Excel].
The column contains different names and this function checks if the entry has either of "AbbVie", "Roche" or "Pfizer" in it. It returns the names from the list that is present in the entry.

```
    (txt as text) =>
[
   
   create_val = (val as text,check as text, output as text) =>
     let 
       output = if Text.Contains(val,check)
       then Text.Combine({output, check},",")
       else output
     in
       output,
    final_value = List.Accumulate({"AbbVie","Roche","Pfizer"},"",(state,current) => create_val(txt,current,state))
][final_value]
```

Comment: Aside from returning a leading comma, you function seems to run OK stand-alone. What kind of input results in the error you are seeing?

Comment: I am invoking it on a column in my table. The column has only text values             
e.g: Arbeitsgemeinschaft Gynakologische Onkologie
AGO-Study Group Ovarian Cancer
Swiss Group for Clinical Cancer Research - SAKK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this one too so I though I'd share how I solved it.

I was using a custom function recursively, as a means to implement looping. It turns out I was modifying variables from the function definition, i.e. variables that the function had been called with. By declaring local variables, the function worked as expected.

Comment: I just had something similar.  I wrote a custom function with the parameter `optional arg_1 as nullable logical`, and then in the function body I had it default to `true` via `arg_1 = if arg_1 = null then true else arg_1`.  This threw the `Operation is not valid` error when applied via `Table.TransformColumns()`.  But everything worked once I changed `arg_1` to `a_1` in the function body: **`a_1`** `= if arg_1 = null then true else arg_1`.